# Tracing user permissions in Google Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

On a certain project, how can one see 'WHO' assigned 'WHOM', 'WHAT' role or permissions?
Example: Person 1 is IAM Admin, and granted Person 2 BigQuery Admin role. Is there a way to trace Person 1 granted Person 2 the respective role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the IAM setpolicy logs via advance filter in cloud console > logging > log viewer:

```
protoPayload.methodName="SetIamPolicy"
protoPayload.serviceName="cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com" 
protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.member="Person2 account"
protoPayload.request.policy.bindings.role="role name"
```

Expand the log, the Person 1 account will shows in "authenticationInfo" section, please note that IAM setpolicy log is kept in 400 days.

Comment: Thanks Hao. This answered my question.